# Hibernate OneToOne With Primary Key being a foreign Key not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, one-to-one

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.4 with Spring Data 2.1.6.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.3.9.Final.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comm_profile")
@NamedQuery(name = "CommProfile.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM CommProfile c")
public class CommProfile implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String customerId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "COMM_PROFILE_MAIN_PROFILE_FK"))
@MapsId
private MainProfile mainprofile;

 ....
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class MainProfile implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private String customerId;


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "mainprofile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private CommProfile commProfile;

protected MainProfile() {

}

public MainProfile(final String customerId, final CommProfile commProfile)      {
    this();
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.commProfile = commProfile;
}  
....
```

I try to persist with the following code:

```
private CommProfile createNewProfile(final String customerId, Lang lang) {

    CommProfile commProfile = new CommProfile(lang);

    MainProfile mainProfile = new MainProfile(customerId, commProfile);
    MainProfile mainProfile2 = mainProfileService.save(mainProfile);
    return mainProfile2.getCommProfile();
}
```

For this I get **attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [...CommProfile.mainprofile]**

I have been doing this using the online documentation and examples but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bidirectional OneToOne relationship, you must set both sides.
In your case the relationship from CommProfile to Mainprofile is missing.

For example:

```
public MainProfile(final String customerId, final CommProfile commProfile)      {
    this();
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.commProfile = commProfile;
    commProfile.setMainProfile(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the answer:

**Handling of relationship**

As correctly pointed out by Tom, If you have a bidirectional OneToOne relationship, you must set both sides of the relationship (call `commProfile.setMainProfile(this);` in MainProfile constructor).

**Spring data repository**

```
@Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

When you pass your entity to the save method, isNew incorrectly concludes that the entity is not new. See `AbstractEntityInformation.isNew` for details.

Use `entityManager.persist(mainProfile);` directly to circumvent that issue.